# Strange behaviour from references in an output stream

Tags: c++, cout, time.h

I have noticed strange behaviour when printing output to a stream.  My code loops through a large dataset and, amongst other things, reads a timestamp from each item.  The timestamp from the first item is stored so an elapsed time can be calculated.

```
CurTime = ev[i].MidasTimeStamp;
RunTimeElapsed = difftime(CurTime,StartTime);
cout << "StartTime: " << ctime(&StartTime) << "CurTime: " << ctime(&CurTime) << "Elapsed: " << RunTimeElapsed << " s" << endl;
```

The output printed to screen shows the same time printed twice e.g:

```
StartTime: Mon Sep 23 14:44:57 2013
CurTime: Mon Sep 23 14:44:57 2013
Elapsed: 360 s
```

But if split the print line into two:

```
cout << "StartTime: " << ctime(&StartTime); 
cout << "CurTime: " << ctime(&CurTime) << "Elapsed: " << RunTimeElapsed << " s" << endl;
```

I get the expected output:

```
StartTime: Mon Sep 23 14:44:57 2013
CurTime: Mon Sep 23 14:50:57 2013
Elapsed: 360 s
```

The only change between the two outputs was to the cout line(s). This is easy enough to work around but I'd like to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation on [`ctime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/):

> The returned value points to an internal array whose validity or value
>   may be altered by any subsequent call to asctime or ctime.

The order of evaluation of subexpressions within the expression is unspecified. In particular, it is legal for the compiler to call `ctime` twice first, then call `operator<<` as necessary. This is what seems to happen in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was really scratching my head on that one.  I'm sorry I missed that in the documentation.

Comment: @Carl So how exactly did you think that the memory leak introduced by `ctime()` returning  a pointer is stuffed, when you yourself do not call `free()`?

Comment: @oswald What an obnoxious way to respond!  I think it is clear from my original question that the significance of ctime() returning a pointer had escaped me.  Thankfully somebody else provided a useful answer.

Comment: @Carl Forgive me my seemingly obnoxious way to respond. I just wanted to point out that you should, whenever a pointer is returned from a function, be extra careful about who is responsible for releasing that memory.